# Create a table with n number of columns using a Razor template

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to create a table of data where I know the number of rows that will be present, but the number of columns will vary. The table will exist inside of a razor template.

Ideally I would use a single foreach loop to iterate over a collection and inside the loop, I would add a column for each object.

Here is the way I have it working right now, but this requires one loop per row. With 30ish rows, this is not an ideal solution.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    @foreach(var o in oCollection)
    {
      <td>@o.Name</td>
    }
  </tr>
  <tr>
    @foreach(var o in oCollection)
    {
      <td>@o.Id</td>
    }
  </tr>
  <tr>
    @foreach(var o in oCollection)
    {
      <td>@o.Address</td>
    }
  </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: I use an HTML table in my example but that is not a requirement. Only that the data is displayed in a table like output.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle example of the output for 2 objects. http://jsfiddle.net/rked00dr/. Here's an example for 3 objects. http://jsfiddle.net/rked00dr/2/

Comment: Can you show us a sample of output you are expecting out of those dynamic columns?

Comment: Also how's your model look like?

Comment: Added fiddle examples to show the desired output. Does the model matter in this case? It's just a class with a bunch of string properties that I want to display.

Comment: what you are looking for data pivoting over a list but it would be more custom as you want pivot over properties of class from the list. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is calling data pivoting. Rather trying to generate it in Razor view you can handle this in your Controller and use pivoted data to avoid the complexity that you already mentioned.

Let say your data looks like:

```
            var list = new List<Entity>();
            list.Add(1, "Thing1", "WithAddress_1");
            list.Add(2, "Thing2", "WithAddress_2");
            list.Add(3, "Thing3", "WithAddress_3");
            list.Add(4, "Thing4", "WithAddress_4");
            list.Add(5, "Thing5", "WithAddress_5");
            list.Add(6, "Thing6", "WithAddress_6");
```

*Note: Don't worry about this initialization I used list extension to get this done.*

Use a function like below though it's not the best approach to Pivot data but it'll do the needful. 
Create an extension method like below. Make sure you replace the `List<Entity>` to you type.

```
Public static class ListExtensions
 {
    Public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ToPivot(this List<Entity> oCollection)
    {
        List<dynamic> parent = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> extended = null;

        foreach (Entity entity in oCollection)
        {
            extended = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (var prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                extended.Add(new { Property = prop.Name, Value = prop.GetValue(entity) });
            }

            parent.AddRange(extended);
        }

        // Grouping of value by property names, so each property
        // represents list of all values w.r.t to that property in given list.
        var grps = from d in parent
                   group d by d.Property
                       into grp
                       select new
                       {
                           Property = grp.Key,
                           Values = grp.Select(d2 => d2.Value).ToArray()
                       };
        return grps;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call this function to your collection.

```
  <table>
    foreach (var item in oCollection.ToPivot())
    {
       <tr>
        <td>
           @item.Property;
        <td>
        foreach (var value in item.Values)
        {
            <td>
                @value;
           </td>
        }
       <tr>
    }
  </table>
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| Id      | 1             | 2             | ... |
| Name    | Thing1        | Thing2        | ... |
| Address | WithAddress_1 | WithAddress_2 | ... |
+---------+---------------+---------------+-----+
```

**my suggested generic version (as per comment below -> jim):**

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ToPivot<T>(this IList<T> oCollection)
{
    var parent = new List<dynamic>();

    try
    {
        foreach (T entity in oCollection)
        {
            var extended = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (var prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                extended.Add(new { Property = prop.Name, Value = prop.GetValue(entity) });
            }

            parent.AddRange(extended);
        }

        // Grouping of value by property names, so each property
        // represents list of all values w.r.t that property in given list.
        var grps = parent.GroupBy(d => d.Property).Select(grp => new
        {
            Property = grp.Key,
            Values = grp.Select(d2 => d2.Value).ToArray()
        });
        return grps;
    }
    catch
    {
        // log the reason perhaps
        return default(dynamic);
    }
}
```

Comment: i would have also suggested the reflection approach, especially given the low number of rows -plus 1 (btw -you could of course have employed generics where required, i.e. Entity -> T along the lines `public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ToPivot<T>(this List<T> oCollection`, follwed by `foreach (T entity in oCollection)` etc- (also, note that you have ucased your `Public` scope

Comment: v - it may be more useful to keep the update as an additional edit, as it's quite opinionated!! :) also, the ToPivot would of course break if a IList<T> contained simply an array of strings etc (i.e. `new string[] { "10.123.345.25", "10.123.342.35", "86.142.64.68" }.ToList();` etc.. but could be tested for in try.catch (added to sample)

Comment: Make sense!!.. Yup I agree. It surely have many areas of improvement. I'll update the answer in free time. But if you already have something on your mind to improve it.. then It's your call.

Comment: Also the List inside the loop can be removed and items can be added to the parent List directly. I see no harm; although I used it but I had something else in mind when I wrote the answer.

Comment: will park it here for now as illustrates the boundaries quite well. liked the answer btw - have a peek at similar type of pivot i proposed a good few years back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466536/whats-your-favourite-linq-method-or-trick#answer-4449790

Answer (score 1):

this would allow you to only have to iterate the collection once to build your columns..

```
@{
    string row1;
    string row2;
    string row3;
    foreach (var o in oCollection)
    {
        row1 += string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", o.Name);
        row2 += string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", o.Id);
        row3 += string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", o.Address);
    }
}
<table>
    <tr>
        @Html.Raw(row1);
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @Html.Raw(row2);
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @Html.Raw(row3);
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get functional, you could do something like this. Where `oCollectionItem` is whatever type is in `oCollection`

```
@{
    List<Func<oCollectionItem, string>> funcs = new List<Func<oCollectionItem, string>>(){
        x => x.Name,
        x => x.Address,
        x => x.ID.ToString(), 
       //repeat for each thing to display
    };
}


<table>
    @foreach(var func in funcs)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach(var item in oCollection)
            {
              <td>@func(item)</td>
            }
        </td>    
    }
</table>
```

Comment: won't this give you a row for each item in collection, instead of a column for each item?

Comment: maybe i got it backwards... let me review

Comment: looks like it works to me.. though it still iterates the collection each time right?

Comment: yes it does. just wanted to post another answer i thought was interesting. i'd probably recommend doing it your way. depends on just how expensive it is to iterate that many times vs having less code for readability.